# How are read/write locks implemented in pthread?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

How are they implemented especially in case of pthreads. What `pthread` synchronization APIs do they use under the hood? A little bit of pseudocode would be appreciated.

Comment: perhaps you could read teh codez?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.cognitus.net/html/howto/pthreadSemiFAQ_10.html) can help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I haven't done any pthreads programming for a while, but when I did, I never used POSIX read/write locks. The problem is that most of the time a mutex will suffice: ie. your critical section is small, and the region isn't so performance critical that the double barrier is worth worrying about.

In those cases where performance is an issue, normally using atomic operations (generally available as a compiler extension) are a better option (ie. the extra barrier is the problem, not the size of the critical section).

By the time you eliminate all these cases, you are left with cases where you have specific performance/fairness/rw-bias requirements that require a true rw-lock; and that is when you discover that all the relevant performance/fairness parameters of POSIX rw-lock are undefined and implementation specific. At this point you are generally better off implementing your own so you can ensure the appropriate fairness/rw-bias requirements are met.

The basic algorithm is to keep a count of how many of each are in the critical section, and if a thread isn't allowed access yet, to shunt it off to an appropriate queue to wait. Most of your effort will be in implementing the appropriate fairness/bias between servicing the two queues.

The following C-like pthreads-like pseudo-code illustrates what I'm trying to say.

```
struct rwlock {
  mutex admin; // used to serialize access to other admin fields, NOT the critical section.
  int count; // threads in critical section +ve for readers, -ve for writers.
  fifoDequeue dequeue; // acts like a cond_var with fifo behaviour and both append and prepend operations.
  void *data; // represents the data covered by the critical section.
}

void read(struct rwlock *rw, void (*readAction)(void *)) {
  lock(rw->admin);
  if (rw->count < 0) {
    append(rw->dequeue, rw->admin);
  }
  while (rw->count < 0) {
    prepend(rw->dequeue, rw->admin); // Used to avoid starvation.
  }
  rw->count++;
  // Wake the new head of the dequeue, which may be a reader.
  // If it is a writer it will put itself back on the head of the queue and wait for us to exit.
  signal(rw->dequeue); 
  unlock(rw->admin);

  readAction(rw->data);

  lock(rw->admin);
  rw->count--;
  signal(rw->dequeue); // Wake the new head of the dequeue, which is probably a writer.
  unlock(rw->admin);
}

void write(struct rwlock *rw, void *(*writeAction)(void *)) {
  lock(rw->admin);
  if (rw->count != 0) {
    append(rw->dequeue, rw->admin);
  }
  while (rw->count != 0) {
    prepend(rw->dequeue, rw->admin);
  }
  rw->count--;
  // As we only allow one writer in at a time, we don't bother signaling here.
  unlock(rw->admin);

  // NOTE: This is the critical section, but it is not covered by the mutex!
  //       The critical section is rather, covered by the rw-lock itself.
  rw->data = writeAction(rw->data);

  lock(rw->admin);
  rw->count++;
  signal(rw->dequeue);
  unlock(rw->admin);
}
```

Something like the above code is a starting point for any rwlock implementation. Give some thought to the nature of your problem and replace the dequeue with the appropriate logic that determines which class of thread should be woken up next. It is common to allow a limited number/period of readers to leapfrog writers or visa versa depending on the application.

Of course my general preference is to avoid rw-locks altogether; generally by using some combination of atomic operations, mutexes, STM, message-passing, and persistent data-structures. However there are times when what you really need is a rw-lock, and when you do it is useful to know how they work, so I hope this helped.

EDIT - In response to the (very reasonable) question, where do I wait in the pseudo-code above:

I have assumed that the dequeue implementation contains the wait, so that somewhere within `append(dequeue, mutex)` or `prepend(dequeue, mutex)` there is a block of code along the lines of:

```
while(!readyToLeaveQueue()) {
  wait(dequeue->cond_var, mutex);
}
```

which was why I passed in the relevant mutex to the queue operations.

Comment: Can you point to a more detailed explanation of why and how to avoid RW locks? I have been using pthread RW locks at places where I feel I shouldn't be and would like to know more about what you are talking about.

Comment: It isn't about avoiding RW locks. As I said in my answer, when you need an RW lock you should use one. The problem is that it is rare to need an RW lock and not to also have bias/fairness requirements. Posix RW locks make no bias/fairness guarantees, and as such are ironically non-portable for those times where you might want to use them. Given it is not hard to implement your own portable RW lock, you may as well.

Comment: Where do you wait for the signals in the code. I see signal( rw->deque ) at several places, but no code to wait on that signal.

Comment: The algorithm you've presented is **a lot** slower than typical ones - the most obvious issue being the spurious wakeups. I'm also failing to see how it handles multiple read lock attempts by the same reader without the possibility of deadlock.

Comment: I explicitly described the algorithm as a starting point for thinking about rw-locks. Reentrancy and performance are both second-order requirements, and would have complicated the answer obscuring the core algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Each implementation can be different, but normally they have to favor readers by default due to the requirement by POSIX that a thread be able to obtain the read-lock on an rwlock multiple times. If they favored writers, then whenever a writer was waiting, the reader would deadlock on the second read-lock attempt unless the implementation could determine the reader already has a read lock, but the only way to determine that is storing a list of all threads that hold read locks, which is very inefficient in time and space requirements.

Comment: Your comment only applies to reentrant rw-locks. As demonstrated in my answer, non-reentrant locks only require a count. Moreover, a list is a very poor choice of data-structure for implementing reentrancy. A cache-conscious combination of short arrays, bitmaps, and linear-hashtables can make the bookkeeping much more space/time efficient.

Comment: By reentrant do you meant recursive? Reentrancy is a much stronger requirement than just recursive locking.